# Transaction log for standalone DB vs AlwaysON availability Group

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups, transaction-log

I have this question on the generation of transaction logs. For a high transaction active DB what is the ratio of log generation if it is a standalone DB and when it is part of SQL Alwayson availability group(synchronous commit).

I am pretty sure it will be high, but how much higher. Rather than doing a test on my own any answer or reference will be helpful.

Note: The perfmon counter do show the numbers for transactions/logs flushed which seems to be really in case of AG. I want to understand if there is a way to limit it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For a high transaction active DB what is the ratio of log generation if it is a standalone DB and when it is part of SQL Alwayson availability group(synchronous commit).

Assuming Full Recovery mode, which AGs require, 1:1.  AGs don't require any additional logging beyond what a Full Recovery database already does.

In Simple recovery mode you might have some minimally logged operations, but for a "high transaction active" database, it's unlikely.  See eg

[SQL Server 2016, Minimal logging and Impact of the Batchsize in bulk load operations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/sql-server-2016-minimal-logging-and-impact-of-the-batchsize-in-bulk-load-operations/)

Comment: Thanks David, Just did a test to validate and its the same. I was under an assumption the synchronous AG will track more activity for the DB on behalf of other replicas. Hence was the doubt.